# How do I get the DispositionEventDate?

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to display DispositionEventDate, DispositionType and @Word from DispositionEvent. To get this information, I will use ChargeHistoryID from ChargeHistory a child of Charge. Then using that ID, I need to compare it with the ChargeHistoryID in Disposition which is a child of DispositionEvent.
Expected output should look like this:

```
<ext:Charge>
        <nc:Disposition>
            <nc:DispositionDate>
                <nc:Date>05/08/2014</nc:Date>
            </nc:DispositionDate>
            <nc:DispositionDescriptionText>Convicted</nc:DispositionDescriptionText>
            <nc:DispositionText>CONV</nc:DispositionText>
        </nc:Disposition>
    </ext:Charge>
```

**Complete xml**

```
<Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="IXML Case Notification Test" MessageID="67078058" xmlns="">
<Case InternalID="1616807927" ID="11747370" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
    <DispositionEvent ID="155092097" Date="05/08/2014" InternalDispositionEventID="1717322912" xmlns:reslib="urn:reslib">
        <DispositionEventDate>05/08/2014</DispositionEventDate>
        <AgingClockActionKey Word="N">Does not affect aging clock</AgingClockActionKey>
        <Disposition ChargeID="10547226" ChargeHistoryID="41858685" InternalChargeID="1616447618" InternalOffenseHistoryID="1636250409">
            <DispositionType Word="CONV">Convicted</DispositionType>
        </Disposition>
    </DispositionEvent>
    <Charge ID="10547226" PartyID="16580814" CurrSentenceID="155092098" InternalChargeID="1616447618" InternalPartyID="1614482843" xmlns:reslib="urn:reslib">
        <ChargeOffenseDate>03/26/2014</ChargeOffenseDate>
        <ChargeHistory ChargeHistoryID="41858685" Stage="Disposition Event" DispositionEventSequence="2" CurrentCharge="true" InternalOffenseHistoryID="1636250409">
            <ChargeNumber>2</ChargeNumber>
        </ChargeHistory>
    </Charge>
</Case>
```

**xslt** Here is the template for the  This is used to display the output for DispositionEventDate, DispositionType and @Word which is CONV.

```
<xsl:template name="ChargeDetails">
        <j:ChargeSequenceID>
            <xsl:value-of select="ChargeNumber"/>
        </j:ChargeSequenceID>
        <j:ChargeStatute>
            <j:StatuteDescriptionText>
                <xsl:value-of select="Statute/StatuteCode"/>
            </j:StatuteDescriptionText>
            <j:StatuteText>
                <xsl:value-of select="Statute/StatuteCode/@Word"/>
            </j:StatuteText>
        </j:ChargeStatute>
        <j:ChargeSeverityDescriptionText>
            <xsl:value-of select="Statute/Degree"/>
        </j:ChargeSeverityDescriptionText>
        <!--/Integration/Case/Charge/ChargeHistory[5]/@ChargeHistoryID-->
        <xsl:if test="@Stage='Disposition Event'">
            <!--<xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::DispositionEventDate[preceding-sibling::DispositionEvent/Disposition[@ChargeHistoryID=current()/@ChargeHistoryID]][1]">-->
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::Integration//DispositionEvent/Disposition[@ChargeHistoryID=current()/@ChargeHistoryID][1]">123
                <nc:Disposition>
                    <nc:DispositionDate>
                        <nc:Date>
                            <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(DispositionEventDate))"/>
                        </nc:Date>
                    </nc:DispositionDate>
                    <nc:DispositionDescriptionText>
                        <xsl:value-of select="DispositionType"/>
                    </nc:DispositionDescriptionText>
                    <nc:DispositionText>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Word"/>
                    </nc:DispositionText>
                </nc:Disposition>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your XSLT (ideally, a small but complete sample), as it is not quite clear what element you are positioned on when you do the `xsl:for-each`. Also, could you show your expected output in this case? Thank you!

Comment: Hello Tim, I have edited the question by adding the template called ChargeDetails. I also have pasted the output for the <ext:Charge> below the xslt code.

Comment: Are you sure you saved your edits? It is still saying "edited 16 hours ago" ;)

Comment: I think you looked at it while I was editing. It took a while to edit the original xml and xslt and add it. It is now updated (edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are positioned on a `ChargeHistory` element, you could change your `xsl:for-each` to this

```
<xsl:for-each 
     select="../../DispositionEvent[Disposition/@ChargeHistoryID=current()/@ChargeHistoryID][1]">
```

Alternatively, you could make use of an `xsl:key`. Define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="Event" match="DispositionEvent" use="Disposition/@ChargeHistoryID" />
```

Then your `xsl:for-each` simplifies to this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('Event', @ChargeHistoryID)[1]">
```

Comment: I used the first suggestion because you are correct I am sitting on ChargeHistory. Thanks for your help.